# Changing internal database to external JDBC in Atlassian crowd

Tags: linux, atlassian-crowd

I have installed Atlassian crowd using the internal database method on Centos 6. Installation went successfully and now i want to use external database (mysql) using JDBC. I cant find the option to accomplish that. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

See Atlassian's documentation for how to [Migrate to Another Database](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Migrate+to+Another+Database):

> This guide applies to situations when you may need to migrate Crowd to another database.